# Custom cl termcap causes vim freeze inside gnu screen

Tags: vim, gnu-screen, terminfo, termcap

I was concerned about the terminal scroll inside `screen`, besides I have configured `altscreen on` it only affects some programs, not taking any effect  when switching between windows.

I know `printf '\ec'` clear the terminal better than the `Ctrl+L` or common `clear` command, so that I have decided to apply this.

The default termcap for `cl` entry is `\E[H\E[J` which is the same as `ho` (`\E[H`) followed by `cd` (`\E[J`) you can get this values if you `echo $TERMCAP` inside a `screen` session.

I wondered if changing `cl` to `\Ec` would cause the effect I expect, and it does, cheers! But unfortunately it caused a huge side effect: arrow keys stopped working inside `vim`.

I am still able to navigate using `H`, `J`, `K` and `L` keys, so that I see no reason for not working with arrow keys.

I want to avoid to change `.vimrc` as it is caused by `screen`, and I can run `vim` inside an `ssh` session so I would have to change the `.vimrc` of all machines.

Here is my current `.screenrc`:

```
vbell off
startup_message off
altscreen on
termcapinfo xterm* ti@:te@:cl=\Ec
#termcapinfo xterm* xn:hs@:cd=\E[J:ho=\E[H
```

I have been trying some variants, with and without `ti` and so on, but the problem seen to be `cl` itself, if its value is `\E[H\E[J` it works, otherwise don't.

To reproduce the problem write the file `$HOME/.screenrc` with the content above and start a session with for instance `screen -ADRS profile`, and then try to `vim .screenrc`, you can see you won't be able to navigate using key arrows on keyboard, only `HJKL` keys.

```
Screen version 4.03.01 (GNU) 28-Jun-15
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Nov 24 2016 16:44:48)
```

Is it possible to have the same behaviour as clearing with `\Ec` and keep the `vim` working?

Note1: as @schily claimed, it isn't necessarily a `termcap` problem, but maybe a `terminfo`, but either way I'm using `termcapinfo` statement on my `.screenrc` that according the manual apply the tweak rule for both `termcap` and `terminfo`, I'm not an expert on `termcap/info`, I just want to solve this.
Note2: running `vim` with `:set term=linux` make it works, but as I have stated before I would like to avoid changing `.vimrc`.
Note3: it affects `less` as well, and probably others, one more enforcement regarding being a `screen` problem.
Note4: I filed a bug: https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?54317

Comment: Why do you believe that `vim` is using `termcap`?

Comment: @schily I'm not making any assumption, I'm just reporting the facts, have you tried to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Well vim links to libterminfo, so it will not be affected from termcap changes. There are currently few editors that use termcap even though termcap is much faster than terminfo.

Comment: As I read from manual, termcapinfo on screenrc is the same as termcap and terminfo tweak both, so, where I write termcap you can assume I'm refering to both termcap and terminfo.

Comment: libterminfo emulates the interfaces from libtermcap, but it never reads the termcap data base.

Comment: I just want to clear with `\Ec` whenever is possible, not only on vim, as well as on window switching, so the normal behaviour leaves the lines the way you could scroll the mouse wheel up and see lines you shouldn't, using `\Ec` would fix it, but it brings me these vim problem, can you help me to solve it?